# Alteryx - Split a string with an uncertain length into 5 characters per column

Tags: regex, alteryx

I am trying to split a string (the string length is uncertain; it could be 500 characters or 1500 characters) into multiple columns, and each column should only contain 5 characters.

For example,
If column A contains the string:
AAGANAB5ARAB7AAAB9AAAC--CAC--1ACMRD
Then, I need Column B to Column H to be:
AAGAN,
AB5AR,
AB7AA,
AB9AA,
AC--C,
AC--1,
ACMRD

Also, the string contains “-“, but it is NOT delimiter. It should also be counted as a part of 5 char strings.

I know RegEx is probably the function I should use, and just by putting "(.....)" in the Regular Expression, Alteryx can extract the first 5 characters. But I don't know how to ask Alteryx to automatically split the entire string (length varies each row) to columns of 5 chars.

Answer (score 1):

In Alteryx, use their [RegEx](https://help.alteryx.com/current/designer/regex-tool) tool (instead of the Formula tool with one of their REGEX expressions).  In the config panel of the RegEx tool, and simply enter `.....` as the RegEx, and the key is to select "Split to Rows"... this will give you rows with a new field that is the result of the applied RegEx.